# Ubuntu 13.04 установка руби

Tags: установка, ruby, ubuntu

Требуется на ubuntu 13.04 установить руби.Решил делать вот по этой статье с хабра http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/49699/  Всё упёрлось в пакет libxml2-dev.

Ругается вот так

```
    ~/soft/ruby-2.0.0-p0$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-devЧтение списков пакетов… ГотовоПостроение дерева зависимостей       Чтение информации о состоянии… ГотовоНекоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вамипакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости: libxml2-dev : Зависит: libxml2 (= 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4) но 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.1 будет установленE: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

Гуглил, ответов нет. Один чувак на каком-то форуме просто отписался что решил, но что и как не указал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так:sudo apt-get -f install

В Kubuntu 12.04 никаких проблем. Вот выхлоп:

```
sudo aptitude install libxml2-dev[sudo] password for ********: Следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты будут установлены:          libxml2-dev 0 пакетов обновлено, 1 установлено новых, 0 пакетов отмечено для удаления, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.Необходимо получить 761 kБ архивов. После распаковки 2 207 kБ будет занято.Получено: 1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libxml2-dev i386 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.4 [761 kB]Получено 761 kБ в 2с (347 kБ/с)      Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета libxml2-dev.(Чтение базы данных ... на данный момент установлено 158299 файлов и каталогов.)Распаковывается пакет libxml2-dev (из файла .../libxml2-dev_2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.4_i386.deb)...Обрабатываются триггеры для man-db ...Настраивается пакет libxml2-dev (2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.4) ...dpkg --get-selections | grep libxml2libxml2                                         installlibxml2-dev                                     installlibxml2-utils                                   install
```

Comment: Перепробовал на 6 разных ос. Проблема в 13-м семействе ubuntu. На 12.10 всё прекрасно установилось. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get autoremove ?

Comment: Что это даст? Удалит неиспользуемые пакеты?

Comment: да, обычно и битые удаляет

Comment: sudo apt-get -f autoremoveЧтение списков пакетов… ГотовоПостроение дерева зависимостей       Чтение информации о состоянии… Готовообновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install libxml2-devЧтение списков пакетов… ГотовоПостроение дерева зависимостей       Чтение информации о состоянии… ГотовоНекоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вамипакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Comment: Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости: libxml2-dev : Зависит: libxml2 (= 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4) но 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.1 будет установленE: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get -f

man apt-get

man aptitude

Comment: не помогло.пробовал sudo apt-get -f autoremove

Comment: sudo apt-get autoremove;sudo apt-get autoclean;sudo apt-get clean

Comment: Результат такой же. Есть ещё варианты?

Comment: **aptitude install libxml2-dev** когда  скажет про зависимости нажмите **`e`**  далее можно, используя **`alt+r`** и **`,`**/**`.`**  , выбрать подходящий вариант, либо, используя **`q`** а потом **`b`** и **`+`**/**`-`**, разрешить зависимости вручную

Comment: @eicto, где ж ты раньше то был)